# Concatenate to create Unique ID and Check in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

friends,
I am looking for a solution where I have  two tables(Tab1 and Tab2). Both has same fields(F1,F2,F3,F4). If I concatenate F2,F3,F4, I get a unique record.
Tab1(Source) has 10 records and Tab2(Dest) has 2 records.
I would like to create a unique id in Source Tab and do the same in Dest Tab, later check which record is not available in Dest Tab and add it.
So records will move from Tab1 to Tab2, if Tab2 doesn't have those records.
let me know how I can accomplish it.

Regards,
Vik

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, there's no reason to concatenate the fields.  You can just use them in your `where` criteria (or `join` criteria).

Here's one option using `not exists`:

```
insert into tab2 (f1,f2,f3,f4)
select f1,f2,f3,f4
from tab1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tab2 t2
    where t1.f2 = t2.f2 and t1.f3 = t2.f3 and t1.f4 = t2.f4
    )
```

This will insert any data from `tab1` into `tab2` that doesn't exist in `tab2` based on `f2, f3, and f4`

Comment: I replaced insert into tab2 (f1,f2,f3,f4)
select f1,f2,f3,f4 with insert into tab2 select * from tab1, can you tell me what is select 1

Comment: @Vik -- It's nothing really, just arguably the easiest thing to `select`.  When using `exists`, you don't have to `select` any fields, it's just trying to see does anything match based on the `where` criteria.  So `select 1` is just a quick way of doing that.  It would work the same with `select f1` for example...

Comment: @sgeddes--Thank you so much for answering my query. It's working perfectly.

Comment: If I have another field f5(date) and has multiple entries for f2,f3,f4, how would I pick up the min date row only ?

Comment: @Vik I'd recommend asking a new question, using sample data and expected results, instead of commenting on old questions.  Also, if this answered your original question, you should accept it by clicking the checkbox beside it.

Answer (score 0):

With left join, fetching all the rows from table1 that do not have matching rows in table2:

```
insert into table2 (f1, f2, f3, f4)
select t1.f1, t1.f2, t1.f3, t1.f4
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.f2 = t2.f2 and t1.f3 = t2.f3 and t1.f4 = t2.f4
where t2.f2 is null and t2.f3 is null and t2.f4 is null
```

Comment: @forpas--Thanks for suggesting another solution. Let me try this also.